# QT ReplaceChild method

Tags: c++, xml, qt

I'm trying to replace the node of xml tree:

```
QFile file("xml1.xml");
file.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
QDomDocument xml;
xml.setContent(file.readAll());

QDomElement root = xml.documentElement();
QDomElement child = searchNode(root,  "Timeout");

QDomElement newChild = xml.createElement("Timeout");
QDomText newNodeText = xml.createTextNode(QString("New Text"));
newChild.appendChild(newNodeText);

root.replaceChild(newChild, child);
```

But nothing happens. child isn't null, root contains all xml fields.
Also root.firstChildElement("Timeout") returns null.
Function searchNode:

```
QDomElement MainWindow::searchNode(const QDomElement& root, const QString& nodeName) {
  QDomElement returning = QDomElement();
  if (!root.firstChild().nodeValue().isEmpty()) {
    if (root.tagName() == nodeName) {
      returning = root;
    }
  }
  if (returning.isNull()) {
    for (auto element = root.firstChildElement(); !element.isNull(); element = element.nextSiblingElement()) {
      returning = searchNode(element,  nodeName);
      if (!returning.isNull()) {
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return returning;
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Envelope>
  <SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <wsa:Action>action</wsa:Action>
  <wsa:To> ADDRESS </wsa:To>
  </SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
  <PullMessages>
  <Timeout>PT2S</Timeout>
  <MessageLimit>1</MessageLimit>
  </PullMessages>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</Envelope>
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Timeout` is not a child of `Envelope` (*variable `root` in your code*). It is a child of `PullMessages`. So `root.firstChildElement("Timeout")` should return a null node. This also explains why `root.replaceChild(newChild, child);` won't work.

[`QDomNode::replaceChild`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdomnode.html#replaceChild):
*Replaces oldChild with newChild. oldChild must be a direct child of this node.*

To make it work you could do something like this:

`oldChild.parentNode().replaceChild(newChild, oldChild);`